# JSON for high chart imported with json.load generated error when using json.dump

Tags: python, json, highcharts, phantomjs, highcharts-convert

I am attempting to write a JSON file for highcharts-convert/phantomJS dynamically with python. I have a valid original.json that works. When i use this simple program to bring it in with json.load and then json.dump it to data.json - the data.json generates an error!

```
import json

with open('orignal.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, separators=(',',':'), ensure_ascii=True)
```

Here is the Error I get when phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js reads it:

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
TRACE:
 -> phantomjs://code/data.js: 2 (in function "injectJs")
 -> phantomjs://code/highcharts-convert.js: 637 (in function "injectResources")
 -> phantomjs://code/highcharts-convert.js: 808
 -> phantomjs://platform/webpage.js: 286 (in function "_onPageOpenFinished")

  phantomjs://code/highcharts-convert.js:723 in onError
Exited with message 'ERROR: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':''
```

Here is the original.json: http://pastebin.com/fAXtmHTc

and here is the json.dump data.json: http://pastebin.com/mXjeNYug
What went wrong? Other than order, they seem the same!

Comment: I saved the 'bad' json to disk, read it in phantomjs 2.1.1 using fs.read, and JSON.parse parsed it without error.

Comment: @snakecharmerb im using  phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile data.json -outfile chart.png    and i get an error trying to make a chart. Is there something i can do different?

Comment: I've tested both of your files (as strings, not as actual files), loading, dumping (with your `json.dump` args) & re-loading, then comparing the "before" and "after" loaded objects. In both cases the loaded objects compared equal. All I can suggest is to try to locate the section in the bad data file that's causing this error; maybe you can prune out stuff from the JSON (but I guess you don't have a lot of latitude there without making the data invalid).

Comment: BTW, I noticed is that you have `false` as a raw JSON object but `"true"` as a string. I know that's got nothing to do with your error message, but it's still a little odd.

Comment: @FightFireWithFire I can't get highcharts to work on my machine, but the broken json si accepted without error at http://export.highcharts.com/.  Maybe check you're definitely picking up the correct file?

Comment: @PM2Ring I did try editing the JSON the output JSON file and simplify it down to one entry by hand, but so far it rejects it on the commandline. I tried it with and without ensure_ascii (both true,false and without the attribute and it still fails!)

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for the export.highcharts.com - it 100% works when cut and pasted into there! But it still doesn't export from python cleanly even tho the JSON seems fine. Is there some kind of LF in it or something?

Answer (score 0):

You are executing this command:

`phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -infile data.json -outfile chart.png`

According to the [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside) (search for "legacy solution", the `-infile` parameter should be:

> The file to convert, the script have to find if this is a javascript
>   file with a options object or a svg file.  It checks the input file
>   for beginning with "<svg", "<?xml" or "<!doctype". Then it's a svg
>   file, otherwise it's presumed to be an options file.

but you are passing it `JSON`, which it can't parse.

Try passing a javascript file like this:

```
var options = { // your JSON here, as a js object };
```